# Undefined data in angularjs ui grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using `angularjs ui grid` here's my code :

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    enableSorting: false,
    expandableRowTemplate: storyboard.customHtml,
    expandableRowHeight: 90,
    enableRowSelection: true,
    multiSelect: false,
    exporterMenuCsv: false,
    // enableGridMenu: true,
    enableSelectAll: true,
    enableColumnResizing: true,
    enableSorting: true,
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi; //set gridApi on scope
        gridApi.core.on.renderingComplete($scope, function() {
            $timeout(function() {
                var gridBodyElem = document.getElementById(gridApi.grid.id + '-grid-container');
                gridBodyElem.addEventListener('mouseup', handleGridClick);
            });
        });
    },
    columnDefs: [
        { field: 'name', displayName: 'Name', cellClass: 'gridField' },
        { field: 'uniqueid', displayName: 'ID', cellClass: 'gridField' },
        { field: 'devicetime', displayName: 'GPS DATE', cellClass: 'gridField' },
        { field: 'adress', displayName: 'Adresse', cellClass: 'gridField' },


        { field: 'company', displayName: 'Company', cellClass: 'gridField' }

    ]
};
```

here's the html template:

```
storyboard.customHtml ='<div style="margin-top:0px;margin-left:10px;"">'                                        
                     + '<i class="fa fa-road" aria-hidden="true" >'+ $scope.km2 +'Km'+'</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
                     + '<i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true">' + $scope.speed2 +'km/h'+'</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
                     + '</div>';
```

the problem is, when I fired a function to get the `$scope.km2` and the `$scope.speed2`...I got them but they show as undefined in the `customHtml` I don't now why??

Comment: `<i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true">{{ speed2  }} km/h</i>`

Comment: No..this template defined in the controller..